# how can i change the color of text and tint color of image of a components using props in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have made a custom button and below is the code.

```
export class MenuItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loading: true
        };
    }

    render() {
        let { navigation, listingname, imagesource,} = this.props;
        return (
            <View >
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.props.onPress}

                    style={[styles.menuStyle]}>

                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                        
                        <Image source={imagesource} style={[styles.menuItemIcon,{tintColor:'black'}]} />
                        <Text style={[styles.menuTextstyle]}>{listingname} </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}


export default MenuItems;
```

Now I have reused it with different value and images . I want to change the tint color and text color of the custom button to blue . Below is the code.

```
                     \<MenuItems listingname="Logout"

            onPress={() => {
                this.RBSheet.close();

                // this.props.navigation.replace('HomeApp', { screen: 'Home' })
                // navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());

                // reset Notification counter 
                this.props.notifyCountrUpdtHndlr(0)
                AuthHelpers.logout(this.props.navigation, true);
            }}
            imagesource ={IMAGE.LOGOUT_ICO}/>



    </View>
```

I want the image color in blue using tint color and text color of the component in  blue. kindly provide the solution and correct the code.

Comment: the color should only be changed of the required component not for every component

Answer (score 0):

Use style

```
const StyledImage = ({style}) => 
  <Image
    style={{width: 20, height: 20, ...style}}
...
  />

<StyledImage style={{tintColor: 'blue'}} />
```

or custom prop

```
const TintedImage = ({tintColor}) => 
  <Image
    style={{width: 20, height: 20, tintColor: tintColor}}
...
  />

<TintedImage tintColor='red' />
```